# How to set the selective captions for TActionToolbar?

Tags: delphi, toolbar, delphi-xe4, tactionmanager

I have a TActionToolbar...But there's one "feature" I can't quite figure out how to control.

From the customize dialog (Vcl.CustomizeDlg.TCustomizeDlg) for a TActionToolbar. Note the caption options listbox:

[image: tactiontoolbar customize dialog]

So how exactly do you *use* selective captions? Right now it appears to be identical to "full" captions, as I can't seem to piece together how you tell Delphi which buttons should display selective captions (or what the selective caption wording should be if it is customizable)
TAction doesn't seem to have any [properties](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/!!MEMBERTYPE_Properties_ActnList_TAction.html) that appear to relate to selective captions. The [description and examples](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_Caption.html) for TCaption didn't seem to get any hints either.

...Or is this just one of those cases where Delphi is showing some sort of standard windows dialog including features Delphi doesn't actually support?

Answer (score 2):

> So how exactly do you use selective captions?

As the same suggests it, it allows to have some buttons showing their caption and some others to don't show it.

Once you've set the action in your toolbar, click on the button. Then go in the inspector and go to the property "ShowCaption" and set it to false. For each button you will do that, the caption will be hidden.

I will try to place a graphic here showing that.

- 1-click the tool button
- 2-go to the object inspector
- 3-see the "ShowCaption" property and set it to "false"
- 4-then see the result, the first button is now showing its caption

[image: Image showing an example of a single button not showing its caption]

I use that from time to time to gain some space on a toolbar with too much button to hide the caption on some obvious button.